# Delete item from array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which I churn out using `$.each` (not jquery but appframework, which is alike). But I need to delete an item, and splice and delete don't seem to work.

```
var cart=Array();
cart[0]=['Beef', 20, 1, 'Well done'];
cart[1]=['Chicken', 15, 1, 'no samonella please'];

$.each(cart,function(index,val){
  $('#cart').append('<div class="devider" data-index="'+index+'">'+val[0]+'<span onclick="delete_item(this);">&#215;</span></div>');
});

function delete_item(that) {
    delete cart[$(that).closest('.devider').attr('data-index')]; // doesn't work
    cart.splice($(that).closest('.devider').attr('data-index'),1); // doesn't work
    cart.splice(1,1); // doesn't work
}
```

So I tried using `parseInt()`, cause you know, why not. But obviously that didn't work. Am I doing something wrong or do I have to use an alternative way.

Like I said, I'm using appframework (jqmobi). So best would be to not rely on jquery seeing appmobi doesn't have all the functions that jquery does. But all js should work.

To be thorough, if I alert `$(that).closest('.devider').attr('data-index')` it gives back the "each" index correct.

Comment: `cart.splice(1, 1)` should work just fine (but your `delete` and other `cart.splice` could, of course, make a mess of things). So I'd guess that something is going on in the code we can't see. How about a minimal yet functional demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com to clear things?

Comment: I don't think you should store data in every product in your cart, why not use cookies or sessions for that? Also, try to keep your code clean, instead of adding `onchange` to your span, add `class="delete"` and use selectors, example: `$('.devider span.delete').click(function(){
$('.devider span.delete').each(function(){
//delete here
});
});`

Comment: Why don't you pass the index of the element directly inside the `delete_item` function from the HTML? So, instead of having `onclick="delete_item(this);"` you'd have `onclick="delete_item(' + index + ');"`, and then the `delete_item` would simply become `cart.splice(index, 1);`(passing `index` as argument instead of `that`)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Greatly appreciated. As for the code neetness, it is not a website, it's an app (phonegap). Also, it has a CMS, so it is not wise to use a bind or something seeing I have limited js capability. As for lightStyle; You are more then right. I will change that immediately, it makes a lot more sense. As for the problem, I know the webkit browser used by Phonegap is light, so some things might indeedbe wrong. Jsfiddle or bin won't do any good. Any other suggestions are always welcome.

Comment: Haha, talking about your tunnelvision here. Maybe time for a break :) The function I called was in test fase, so the array was rebuilt after every delete and thus it did delete and function proper, but rebuild right after. Sorry and thanks, my excuse: 18th hour straight. Break time :)